# pdfx + hyperref prevents setting PDF metadata [incompatible packages]

Tags: hyperref, pdf-a

#### *Edit:* Apparently `hyperxmp` and `pdfx` are incompatible.

I'm using the `pdfx`, and then `\hypersetup` and the `hyperxmp` package to set metadata as I like. I've run into two issues.

1. The metadata doesn't seem to be set now I'm using `pdfx`.
2. 'pdftitle has already been set' etc. warnings.

Any suggestions?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a-3u,pdf17]{pdfx}

\title{BMC}
\subtitle{Pret\ldots}
\author{me}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfcreator=pdfLaTeX,
    pdfproducer={\@author},
    pdfapart=3, % need hyperxmp for this
    pdfaconformance=U % need hyperxmp for this
}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't use hyperxmp and pdfx together. They are incompatible.

Comment: Ah. Oooops. Sorry for the dodgy question then.
In that case, would you have any recommendations for how to set some of the keys like `pdfaconformance`?

Comment: It is not a dodgy question - it is one of the open problems how to get such packages to cooperate. But you don't need hyperxmp here: pdfx will set the keys, you don't need to do something. But the value is a lie: pdfx doesn't tag the pdf, so you don't have a "U" conformance.

Comment: I was under the impression from the documentation that it did.
Also, without hyperxmp I still have no metadata set :(

Comment: You probably need an xmpdata file, see the documentation of pdfx (I have it lying around in my test folder from some earlier test.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about `hyperxmp`, but for sure `pdfx` package loads `xmpincl` to handle the expected XMP metadata.
Your problem could arise from a slight syntax confusion.

**1. Your approach**

```
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfcreator=pdfLaTeX,
    pdfproducer={\@author},
}
```

should work, as long as :

- you have loaded `hyperref`
- you don't have loaded `pdfx`  (see [`pdfx` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf?page=17)  page 17)
- you did'nt use `\maketitle` which by default empties both `\@title` and `\@author`

A MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext} % for example text only
\title{A simple title}
\author{A cute author}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX with hyperref},
    pdfproducer={\@author},
    pdfsubject={Some answer about metadata},
    pdfkeywords={LateX  hyperref},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and the meta data shown in PDF-Xchange and Adobe Reader:
[image]

.
 **2. Another option**, without `hyperref` , using pdfLaTeX's command `\pdfinfo`, used as:

```
   \pdfinfo {   
      /Title (\@title)
      /Author (\@author)
      /Subject (\@suject)
      /Keywords (\@keywords) 
   }
```

The MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{A simple title}
\author{A cute author}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\pdfinfo {   
          /Title (\@title)
          /Author (\@author)
          /Subject (Some answer about metadata)
          /Keywords (LateX  hyperref) 
       }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and the result:
[image]

**3. if you load  `pdfx`**, the metadata set  relies on the `\jobname.xmpdata` file
which could look as (see [`pdfx` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf?page=17)  page 6):

```
\Title{Baking through the ages}
\Author{A. Baker\sep C. Kneader}
\Language{en-GB}
\Keywords{cookies\sep muffins\sep cakes}
\Publisher{Baking International}
\CoverDisplayDate{1er\ avril\ 1999}
\CoverDate{1999-04-01}
```

and as said in 1., `\hypersetup` method is disabled.

A third  MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a-3b,pdf17]{pdfx}
\title{A simple title}
\author{A cute author}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname .xmpdata}
\Title{Another simple title}
\Author{A cute author}
\Subject{Some answer about metadata}
\Keywords{LateX \sep hyperref} 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and its result:
[image]

Please notice that:

- I used `pdfa-3b` as `pdfa-3u`                             is not suitable according to @UlrikeFischer answer
- In the 3rd scheme (pdfx) the title ,is the one written in the `.xmpdata`, independently of  `\title` in the main document
- The keywords creator, producer and others of the same kind are usually automatically set by `pdflatex` and `pdfx`, and could require much more effort if you really want to customize them.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer @Jhor, a few issues unfortunately:
With (1) I get "Option 'pdftitle' has already been used, (hyperref) setting the option has no effect" (and no metadata), (2) gives me the title "spacefactor @m {}title", (3) looks promising. Is there any way that could be adjusted to (a) set those values dynamically (with `\title` etc.), and (b) do you know if I can use that for keys like `pdfapart`?

Comment: I updated my answer with three MWE and the corresponding metadata display. Yes one can set them dynamically, but it's very tricky. I can post some ideas if you ask another question specifically  on this topic. I never heard anything about `pdfapart`

Comment: With (a) I'm afraid I unintentionally mislead you. I meant use `\title` stored in `\@title` to set `\Title`. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

`pdfx` as of March 2020 uses `xmpincl` which is incompatible with `hyperxmp`. But you probably don't need pdfx. Hyperxmp is the more elegant way to deal with metadata since it integrates seamlessly with `hyperref` and `\maketitle` and does not require external files. It works both with PDF/A-1b and PDF/A-3u.

```latex
%\pdfobjcompresslevel=0 %uncomment for Texlive
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{mmap} %only needed for pdfTeX

\title{BMC}
\subtitle{Pret\ldots}
\author{me}

\hypersetup{%
    pdfapart=1,
    pdfaconformance=b
}

\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3} file{sRGB.icc}
\pdfcatalog{%
  /OutputIntents [
    <<
      /Type /OutputIntent
      /S /GTS_PDFA1
      /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
      /OutputConditionIdentifier (sRGB)
      /Info (sRGB)
    >>
  ]
}

\begin{document}

lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I can get pdf A-3u compliant without it, which is something I'm trying to do.

Comment: So you have not tried my example before downvoting? Or did it not work?

Comment: I didn't downvote ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ but this is why I don't think it will work, from the manual: 

The new option ‘pdfa’ tries to avoid violations of PDF/A in code generated by hyperref. However, the result is usually not in PDF/A, because many features aren’t controlled by hyperref (XMP metadata, fonts, colors, driver dependend low level stuff, ...).

Comment: You _think_? I said it's working! XMP is handled by `hyperxmp`, fonts are automatically embedded, for colours I included some code. You are right, `pdfa` alone in `hyperref` does not to the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with solution 1 and 2, ie without pdfx  you can use `\@title` `\@author` and `\@date`. Provided you do it before `\maketitle`, or patch it to avoid erasure.

My answer was related to solution 3, as a macro in a `filecontents` environment will be written verbatim in the file. So you will need a specific `\write` with small problems of encoding if you use letters out of the 128 ASCII range.